# How do I access through Dependency injection services from a nested class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Let's say I have this code (generically) and let's say I need to use ILogger in class C and i don't need it in classes A and B

```
public class A
{
    var classB = new B();
}
public class B
{
    var classC = new C();
}
public class C
{
    //Here I want to use the Ilogger service
}
```

But it seems unreasonable to pass through the constructor along this entire chain, and with the increase in the services used, the constructor will only grow. So how do I properly call services in class C?
Thanks

Comment: What is the problem with the constructor growing? You still only care about the dependencies that that service needs. Also, I don't see any [nested classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types) here. Is your title (or example) wrong?

Comment: Add the relevant constructor arguments in such way that you can construct the following graph: `new A(new B(new C(new Logger())))`.

Comment: Read [What to inject and what not to inject](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1/137) to get a grasp on how to decide to inject objects or new them in code.

Comment: The text I referred to in my earlier comment comes from the book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://cuttingedge.it/book/). Please note that a [Russian translation](https://cuttingedge.it/book/russian) is also available.

Comment: Probably (one of) the best resources on the topic: https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing dependency injection, you have no choice but to pass an implementation of `ILogger` to each new `C`. This is problematic because if a class needs to create a new `C`, where does it, in turn, get an `ILogger` implementation from to pass in? And this problem grows with each class that decides it requires `ILogger`.

The answer is typically to use an inversion of control container, such as the one built into .NET these days, or another (Castle Windsor, Autofac, etc). In that case, `A` and `B` won't call constructors directly. Instead, `B` will depend on `C` and `A` will depend on `B`. The IoC container will create the entire object graph, filling in all the dependencies as required.

```
public class A : IA
{
    private IB _b;

    public A(IB b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }
}

public class B : IB
{
    private IC _c;

    public B(IC c)
    {
        _c = c;
    }
}

public class C : IC
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public B(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
// Assuming A, B, C, and ILogger have all been registered with the container:
var a = Container.Resolve<IA>();
```